# load text file from DLL in exe and ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, web-config, configuration-files

I wrote a C# 4.5.1 class framework as class library project (dll). This dll needs to read from an external text files  which has some information that all dll's callers (e.g. console apps) must use.

Note: i am aware that this not considered best pratice and only exe or web app should have config file. However, in this case this was considered the best solution from the dev team.

in a new project the dll is used by a asp mvc app (web api). Unfortunatley it fails to load the text file at run-time. 
Is possible to read the text file, inside the dll, in a way that works from both exe and asp.net app?

Comment: This is likely a permissions issue.  Does ASP.NET process security context allow access to the file that DLL is trying to read?  What error message do you get?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @LB2: it is not! I am not that far. The question is more about code/C#/.Net. How can i load the text file in the dll? I cannot use  Server.MapPath("~/myfile.txt") because I don’t want to put any dependency from the HTTPServer utility. I cannot use something like: Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "myfile.txt") because I will not work on ASP MVC. Is possible to solve it in one simple way?

Comment: @CharlieC How does your DLL suppose to know where file is located? Is it something that is provided by the consumer code of the DLL (i.e. ASP.NET project), is it expected to be in the same folder as the DLL? Registry key that contains the path?

Comment: the dll wants to load myfile.txt, so it knows the file name. Myfile.txt is part of the visual studio project and it is deployed with the dll. However, AFAIK the path (at runtime) of myfile.txt changes depending on the type of applciation (ASP MVC or simple console app). My question is: is there any way to load the file in a way that works everywhere?